# Mapbox Studio: can you change the style after the fact?

Tags: mapbox

Is it possible to change the base style of a custom style after the fact in Mapbox Studio? If yes, how? I looked around the UI and in the documentation but couldn't find how.

Say I created a private style from the Vintage designer style (for example's sake), then added and customized layers by importing tilesets, can I switch to the another base style (e.g. North Star), or do I need to start a new custom style from the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. **Mapbox Studio** is just a GUI for generating Javascript; it outputs a giant JSON file.

(A Mapbox Style is just a JSON object.)

Each of your data layers is included in that JSON (and can be copied and pasted into another style JSON).

Use these instructions to learn the process:

https://mapbox.com/help/transfer-styles-between-accounts

Hope that helps!